# How to disable Entry input until double-clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm developing a GUI using python 3.6 but I need the user to double-click on a [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) `Entry` widget to allow input (to prevent modification of fields by accident), instead of just press any key to input text.

- Is there any way to prevent the user input by keystroke until double
  click on `Entry`?

I've tried by first to override events with the methods below to unbind keystrokes but none of them worked, so re-definition of new bind (double click) is not yet implemented.

```
Entry.unbind_all('<Key>')
Entry.unbind_all('<KeyPress>')
Entry.unbind_all('<KeyRelease>')
```

Comment: See <Double-Button-1> at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way of doing preventing the user input by keystrokes until a double-click, is simply manipulating the state of an `Entry` with double click and focus out events. As in by default every widget is read-only, when double-clicked a single one gets enabled, and when lost focus it's read-only again:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def on_double_click(widget):
    widget['state'] = 'normal'


def on_lose_focus(widget):
    widget['state'] = 'readonly'


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    entries = list()
    for i in range(3):
        entries.append(tk.Entry(root, state='readonly'))
        entries[-1].bind('<Double-Button-1>',
                                lambda e, w=entries[-1]: on_double_click(w))
        entries[-1].bind('<FocusOut>',
                                    lambda e, w=entries[-1]: on_lose_focus(w))
        entries[-1].pack()
    tk.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```